# map over tibble columns while preserving groups

Tags: r, dplyr, functional-programming, purrr

I have a grouped tibble. I would like to use `map()` to iterate over the columns of the tibble. And within each column, I would like `map()` to act separately on each group. In other words, I would like `map()` to respect the grouping structure of the tibble.

But `map()` doesn't seem to respect the grouping structures of tibbles. Here is a minimal example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data(iris)
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  map(length)
```

In the iris dataset, there are three species and four columns (not counting "Species"). I would therefore like `map()` to return a list of 3 × 4 = 12 lengths, or else to return a nested list that has, in total, 12 lengths. But it returns a list of 5 elements: one for each column, counting the grouping column. Each of these five elements is simply the total length of a column (150). How can I adapt the code above to provide the result that I want?

In this minimal example, a satisfactory alternative to using `map()` is

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(
    mutate(across(everything(), length))
  )
```

which returns

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
* <fct>             <int>       <int>        <int>       <int>
1 setosa               50          50           50          50
2 versicolor           50          50           50          50
3 virginica            50          50           50          50
```

But in most cases, this alternative won't work. The problem is that I'll usually want `summarize()` and `mutate` to return `loess()` objects, not integers. And when I try to get them to return `loess()` objects, they choke with errors like

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`.
x Input must be a vector, not a `loess` object.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>`do` allows you to do work on a group at a time</strike>

**Edit**: as you said `do` is superseded, and this is the more straight-forward (and encouraged) way of doing it. (The issue I had trying this before my `do` answer was I was missing the use of `cur_data()`.)

```r
colnms <- names(iris)[2:4]
colnms
# [1] "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(
    other = colnms,
    mdl = map(colnms, ~ loess(as.formula(paste("Sepal.Length ~", .x)),
                              data = cur_data()))
  )
# Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
#   pseudoinverse used at 0.0975
# Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
#   neighborhood radius 0.2025
# Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
#   reciprocal condition number  2.8298e-016
# Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
#   There are other near singularities as well. 0.01
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
# # Groups:   Species [3]
#   Species    other        mdl    
#   <fct>      <chr>        <list> 
# 1 setosa     Sepal.Width  <loess>
# 2 setosa     Petal.Length <loess>
# 3 setosa     Petal.Width  <loess>
# 4 versicolor Sepal.Width  <loess>
# 5 versicolor Petal.Length <loess>
# 6 versicolor Petal.Width  <loess>
# 7 virginica  Sepal.Width  <loess>
# 8 virginica  Petal.Length <loess>
# 9 virginica  Petal.Width  <loess>
```

Comment: Thank you, @r2evans. That does look good. I note, though, that [`do()` has been superseded](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/do.html); I worry that it'll be removed from the dplyr package before long.  /  The ?do documentation says that `do()` has been superseded by a combination of `summarize()`, `nest_by()`, and `across()`. I'll look further at those commands, especially `nest_by()`, to see whether it can help. But thank you again for calling my attention to `do()`.

Comment: See my edit, I think that'll do it for you :-)

Comment: Thank you—this is great. I had no idea about `cur_data()`. It seems quite useful.